# Procedure created with compilation errors

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

Below is the procedure I have created. When I execute it I'm getting "*Procedure created with compilation errors*" I don't understand where I did mistake in below procedure code, someone help me by finding error in the code

```
create or replace PROCEDURE newprocedur(inMerid IN VARCHAR2,outCount OUT NUMBER) AS  
  CURSOR c1 IS 
    select CLIENT_COUNT 
     from OP_TMER_CONF_PARENT 
    where MER_ID = inMerid 
    FOR UPDATE OF CLIENT_COUNT;
BEGIN
  Open c1
  loop
    fetch c1 into outCount;
    exit when c1%NOTFOUND;
    outCount:=outCount+1;
    update OP_TMER_CONF_PARENT 
       set CLIENT_COUNT = outCount 
     where current of c1;
  end loop;
  close c1;
END;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many records are you expecting to update? If just 1, you can do this in a single SQL statement! Hint: use the `returning` clause.

Comment: Something like: `update op_tmer_conf_parent set client_count = client_count + 1 where mer_id = inMerid returning client_count into outCount;`

Answer (score 3):

1- check for errors and see where error is
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788556/how-to-find-the-error-causing-ora-06575)

2- You missed a semicolon in 5th line-
should be

```
Open c1;
```

Comment: When ll the lock for particular row ll get release if i use this FOR UPDATE OF CLIENT_COUNT ?

Answer (score 1):

In SQL*Plus you can use the command

```
show errors
```

to show you the errors in the PL/SQL code that was just compiled. See http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12041.htm

I'm not familiar with PL/SQL Developer, but TOAD does this automatically and show you the errors allowing you to quickly jump to the line(s) containing the error(s).

Comment: PLSQL Developer does this too, but only if the program is compiled using a Program window type.